# Rails pushing content dynamically after finishing request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

At the moment, im building a Website with Ruby on Rails.

Problem: 
My Website is using different foreign API's for getting Data, for example the Amazon Product Advertising API. If i load e.g. 10 objects at once, it tooks to mutch time.
Its possible to load each object particular? (If one request finished push it with javascript on the page, or something like that) The user should be able to read the first objects while the rest of the content is loading in the background.

simple example:

```
list.each do |object|
  result << AmazonRequest.getItem(object)
  [And now push the changed result list to the view]
end
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks :)

Comment: Certainly possible, use ajax requests or streaming.  Can you post more info about your controller and view/partials?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know RoR, but if you do not need to have all the different API results on the server before sending them out (which seems to be the case), you could just make multiple ajax requests and display content from the different APIs independently.